# Create a csv file with file name and path specified

Tags: c#, csv

I know this should be simple but I am naive in c#. I have the following object to generate as csv. and I am successfully able to generate a csv string using the method [here](https://gist.github.com/SuperYeti/959854)

```
[Serializable]
public class UserSession
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserGuid { get; set; }
    public string MachineGuid { get; set; }
    public Guid SessionGuid { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LogOffTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? DesktopReady { get; set; }
    public bool IsReadable { get; set; }
    public int SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to save this file in a specified path (for eg :

> c://csvfolder/{myFilename}.csv

Can anyone suggest a method to write this csv file to `'myFilename.csv'` and save it in `c://csvfolder` in `c#`??

Comment: System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\csvfolder\myFilename.csv", text); where text is the csv string you created

Comment: Btw. if any of the fields (string representation) contains the separator, you're gonna have a bad time...

Comment: Well, if *one* field contains a separator, how do you distinguish it from being *two* fields? Usually by either escaping the separator or enclosing the field in double quotes. Now what if the field contains the escape character or double quotes? What about line breaks? You get down a rabbit hole quite fast. CSV sounds easy, but corner cases can make it troublesome. See [CSV trouble](http://www.secretgeek.net/csv_trouble) for example.

Comment: Thanks @Corak... I think i will find some other method for creating csv...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be pretty simple. It looks like you have a generic class that can serialize your object into a string buffer.

All there's left is to take the string containing the CSV data and write it to a file. Fortunately that's quite trivial in C#:

```
string path = @"c:\csvfolder\myFilename.csv";

// assuming there's a UserSession object called userSessionObject..
string csvData = ToCsv<UserSession>(",", new [] {userSessionObject});
File.WriteAllText(path, csvData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, for saving the CSV File (Includes the creation of CSV)

```
    string path = "c://csvfolder";                      
    string fileName = "FileName.csv";

    StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(path, false);

     SW.Write( /*Can create the comma sperated items*/);
    /*Create y our CSV file data here*/

    fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
    int BUFFER_SIZE = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
    int nBytesRead = 0;
    Byte[] Buffer = new Byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    nBytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    fs.Close();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```